# Purposefully pollute data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am struggling to find some answers online to this question. I have a dataset which I want to purposefully pollute. I am mining association rules and I want to run some tests. Ideally I want to randomly select x% of cells and replace them with "Null" or empty space. Does anyone have any recommendations on how this could be done?

Thanks

Comment: Answered here [Randomly delete 30% of cells data in an MS excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45982743/3536342)

Comment: A formula based solution would be to add a new sheet and have use IF statments to either get the cell from the data sheet or put in a blank if it met your criteria. This may get bogged down depending how much rows X col your data is. But it should be a one time application by "setting" your polluted data with a copy-> paste values.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Python...

If it's an 'old' xls file use [xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) and [xlwt](https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/)

If it's a 'new' xlsx file, use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

**Example using openpyxl**

30 Random cells obliterated

[image]

```
import openpyxl as xl
import random

wb = xl.open("Book1.xlsx")
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
for n in range(30):
    r = random.randint(1,ws.max_row)      #  Note row indexes start at 1
    c = random.randint(0,ws.max_column-1) #  Note column indexes start at 0
    ws[r][c].value=None
wb.save("Book1b.xlsx")
```

[image]